# (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, http-status-code-413

I have WCF service, and I have a method when I want to pass parameter as big string (over 1mb)

I run this wcf and in WCF Test Client I changed configuration as is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
```

And when I try invoke this method I still have 413 request entity too large.

Comment: Did you change it on *both* ends? The server and the client?

Comment: I added to the client : <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              </binding>  but I still get this same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Matt Burland suggested, you need to configure the service end as well as the client. See [Configuring Services Using Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932(v=vs.110).aspx) for details. The task is not much different from what you have done on the client end of the wire. Here's an excerpt from the aforementioned article.

> WCF uses the System.Configuration configuration system of the .NET
>   Framework. When configuring a service in Visual Studio, use either a
>   Web.config file or an App.config file to specify the settings. The
>   choice of the configuration file name is determined by the hosting
>   environment you choose for the service. If you are using IIS to host
>   your service, use a Web.config file. If you are using any other
>   hosting environment, use an App.config file.

I would suggest not setting everything to `int.MaxValue` as have a [`MaxReceivedMessageSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbindingbase.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=vs.110).aspx) set to 2GB opens you up to DOS (Denial-Of-Service) attacks and the like. The remarks section of the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` property even states:

> The size of the messages that can be received on the wire by services
>   using the WSHttpBindingBase is bounded by the amount of memory
>   allocated for each message. This bound on message size is intended to
>   limit exposure to denial of service (DoS) attacks.

You might just be trying to get it to work at this point, but it is far from recommended to leave it this way.

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced the same issue and solved the problem.
Working code-

[(413) Request Entity Too Large in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325123/413-request-entity-too-large-in-wcf?answertab=votes#tab-top)
Follow the app.config code. This is working and using this I can able to send large file

```
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" >
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ForecastREST_API.RESTServiceImplBehavior" name="ForecastREST_API.RestServiceImpl">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:59624/RestServiceImpl.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ForecastREST_API.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="Web" bindingConfiguration="myBinding">
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
            <dispatcherSynchronization asynchronousSendEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ForecastREST_API.RESTServiceImplBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42202982/send-big-data-to-wcf-413-request-entity-too

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,
In the web.config app side:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXXXX" 
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and on the web.config services side you need to add this code in the next tags:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXXXX" 
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
            messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" 
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings> 
    <services>
      <service name="ServiciosSoporteVital.WCFCaso">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IXXXXXX"
                  contract="ServiciosSoporteVital.IWCFCaso"/>
      </service>
    </services>     
</system.serviceModel>
```

The most important is the relationship through the binding name and bindingConfiguration in both applications.