# Sending large file (>10 MB) through WCF rest service

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

Previously I am sending file (less than 63 KB ) through WCF Rest service then it send successfully but when the file size is greater than  65 KB, it throws an exception. After that I configure the web.config file like below and it works fine.

```
 <bindings>
 <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas/>
    </binding>        
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Now i am sending 10 MB file and also increase the size in web.config file but got the same exception.

I added below configuration setting :

```
 <bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
     <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="525288"></readerQuotas>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

What is needed to fix this?

Comment: So what exactly *is* the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you receive this error on client side. remember you have to set the max size at client side!!!
Read [Derek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723894/413-request-entity-too-large/26725542#26725542). Thats really helpfull.