# ASP.NET web service 413 request entity too large error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, iis

I have an older ASP.NET API web service using .net 4.5.2 and I am posting an object that contains a base64 image to my controller without any problem. The issues come now when I try to post data with more and larger images and I am getting the 413 request entity too large error. I have been looking up things and tried everything I could find on the net with no luck. I am looking to upload files about 10MB in size. One thing that leads me to believe its server related is when running the service under IIS Express I can upload large files locally.

I have tried adding MaxRequestLength and MaxAllowableContentLength to the web config.

```
<system.web>
    <!-- tell IIS to let large requests through -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="52428800" />

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

I have also made a change on my windows 2012 R2 server in IIS v6.2 to allow larger files. I have also adjusted the UploadReadAhead value on the server.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't have anything special in API config class.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
}
```

The bindings in my config for this service

```
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureServerBindingWithUserNameRest"  maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800">
            <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="10485760" />
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurityRest">
            <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: maybe in web.config <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="...."> look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config

Comment: I had a look at the tagged SO and tried a few things, no luck.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58566617/3310091
You can configure at the `startup.cs` with `services.Configure<FormOptions>`

Comment: The below URL can help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26725542/12241692)

Comment: This could also be an error thrown by a load balancer (for example a Nginx) that seats in front of the web server. If there's a Nginx in front, the admin needs to increase the value of the property client_max_body_size.

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net

Comment: @scottlafoy I think I'm facing something similar. Did you get it work finally?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this solution, try to increase the upload size limit. IIS uses uploadReadAheadSize parameter in applicationHost.config and web.config files.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Select the site
3. Double click "Configuration Editor"
4. Select `system.webServer` and then `serverRuntime`
5. Modify the `uploadReadAheadSize` value to `2147483647`
6. Click "Apply"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this but its still refusing with the request entity too large error

Comment: Can you share what kind of bindings you've configured in the web.config?

Comment: I added it to the end of the question.

Comment: You can also try to change `maxRequestEntityAllowed` parameter, It specifies the maximum number of bytes allowed in the request body.

Comment: In the last picture on my question I have MaxRequestEntityAllowed set, it is the one right above uploadReadAheadSize . Is this the one you are referring to?

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this error while sendig zipped files containing a large amount of PDFS, the solution I found was to also add to the web config requestLengthDiskThreshold apart from the maxRequestLength:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="268435456" requestLengthDiskThreshold="268435456" executionTimeout="600"/>
```

I also added a longer timeout than the 90 preset so it had time to send the file. Just have in mind that the requestLengthDiskThreshold must not exceed the maxRequestLength.

Comment: I gave this a try, didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider executing a dummy get request just before posting large content. When a https connection is initialized, this first request should not be very large. Once the https connection is initialized proceeding requests are not limitted.

Answer (score 0):

The "**413 Payload Too Large**" error typically indicates that the server has a limit on the size of the payload (data) that can be sent in a single request, and the request you're making exceeds that limit.

In your ASP.NET application, check the web.config file for the following settings and adjust them accordingly:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="your_max_file_size_in_kb" executionTimeout="seconds" />
</system.web>
```

Replace **your_max_file_size_in_kb** and **seconds** as per your need.

If you're using multipart requests for file uploads, check the web.config for the following settings:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="your_max_file_size_in_bytes" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Replace **your_max_file_size_in_bytes** with the maximum allowed file size in bytes.

This resolved my issue for uploading large size file. Thanks!